# Isometric projection start point

Tags: cocos2d, isometric

I have a question about isometric projection: Why did in all tutorials and examples start point for isometric is in left top corner ?
For example in cocos2d 3.1 my start screen point in left bottom, so left top isometric position will nearly 1500,1500. So is it normal to make start isometric point in left bottom corner ? i mean :

```
x,y
0,3 1,3 2,3 
0,2 1,2 2,2 
0,1 1,1 2,1
0,0 1,0 2,0
```

or better

```
0,0 1,0 2,0
0,1 1,1 2,1
0,2 1,2 2,2
0,3 1,3 2,3
```

sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question of semantics. How your local coordinate system is build is your own preferebly choice. In the web browser for example origo is located in the top-left corner, which usually adapts in web-based games.

So, to answer your qestion; no it doesn't matter. As long as you understand your code and are using the tools as they are intended. If you have (0,0) in the bottom-left, then go for it!

Comment: thanks, it's my first time and i thought, that if a future something may go wrong with bottom left start, but if it's ok than will do a same.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of axes is really arbitrary, that is, a matter of convention.

Traditionally, in 2D graphics, the x-axis goes left to right and the y-axis top to bottom. This is because of the scanline of your monitor which follows the reading order of Western languages.

In 3D graphics, the coordinate systems typically have the x-axis like in 2D, but the y-axis going from bottom to top. This follows the mathematics tradition.